# LaTeX - PGF groupplot - polar axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I can't find the answer anywhere, is it [and how] possible to make a group plot of multiple polar graphs? For grouping, I use `pgf.groupplot` library, for polar axis, I use `\begin{polaraxis}` from `pgf` package too. But it can be another library or package.

*I want to visualize polar distribution characteristics of audio signal for each third-octave band from 20 to 20.000 Hz*

*The target page should look somehow like this picture:*

[image: Third-octave bands]

Comment: The `groupplot` library won't work here, I believe. The easiest way to do this might be to put all the axes into a single `tikzpicture`, and taking care of the placement manually. Could you edit your question to include a little more detail on how you want to lay out the plots, and how flexible the solution should be?

Comment: If you want to show something from 20Hz to 20kHz, wouldn't a Bode plot be the way to go? Probably something like [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/bode-plot/)?

Comment: @Tom Bombadil That is a misunderstood, each frequency band [20Hz, 31.5Hz, 40Hz, ... , 16kHz, 20kHz] has its own polar plot with an angle on x-axis and a pressure level on y-axis, it can't be merged into one plot.

Comment: Ah, Okay. How many of these do you need to do? So should it be fully automatic or is fine tunung by hand an option?

Comment: It's 30 plots, so if there wouldn't be another way, it's not impossible to do it manually.

Comment: What I did when I had 30 or more plot in one picture was to create a Lua script (but you can use what language you prefer) that generated the tex file that grouped all the plots. All of them were in one figure but every plot was a sub figure (package subfig). In this way, you have all the plots in one figure but they are organized in subfigure with different labels. I hope I was clear! If not, tell me!

Comment: I suppose the point data comes from some kind of file?

Answer (score 3):

This solution reads the data from a file. It let's you chose haw many plots there are in a row and how they should be scaled. But it will not break across pages, so at this number of plots you should use the `[p]` float placement specifier:

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
ang f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6  f7  f8  f9  f10 f11 f12 f13 f14 f15 f16 f17 f18 f19 f20 f21 f22 f23 f24 f25 f26 f27 f28 f29 f30
-90 0.5 0.46    0.62    0.95    0.33    0.43    0.58    0.42    0.28    0.51    0.87    0.49    0.55    0.25    0.64    0.11    0.09    0.74    0.19    0.64    0.15    0.77    0.61    0.05    0.3 0.57    0.69    0.46    0.24    0.4
-60 0.73    0.47    0.56    0.63    0.57    0.73    0.43    0.39    0.66    0.24    0.62    0.56    0.88    0.35    0.36    0.77    0.87    0.29    0.33    0.91    0.74    0.58    0.46    0.16    0.8 0.91    0.44    0.91    0.82    0.43
-30 0.41    0.33    0.71    0.88    0.56    0.33    0.59    0.22    0.01    0.27    0.1 0.25    0.35    0.59    0.02    0.23    0.26    0.76    0.22    0.78    0.15    0.97    0.59    0.77    0.85    0.18    0.51    0.09    0.96    0.1
0   0.07    0.33    0.29    0.04    0.66    0.1 0.19    0.43    0.7 0.84    0.87    0.14    0.41    0.43    0.23    0.66    0.1 0.74    0.77    0.51    0.05    0.08    0.7 0.65    0.76    0.18    0.07    0.32    0.56    0.36
30  0.59    0.17    0.24    0.29    0.26    0.72    0.46    0.68    0.47    0.52    0.42    0.85    0.07    0.84    0.31    0.29    0.39    0.64    0.3 0.73    0.07    0.58    0.3 0.45    0.83    0.2 0.63    0.23    0.45    0.41
60  0.46    0.15    1   0.11    0.15    0.35    0.91    0.48    0.4 0.5 0.25    0.52    0.67    0.34    0.67    0.7 0.33    0.03    0.16    0.74    0.58    0.38    0.56    0.28    0.4 0.94    0.32    0.64    0.86    0.09
90  0.84    0.42    0.01    0.49    0.73    0.88    0.35    0.58    0.11    0.09    0.73    0.45    0.58    0.96    0.62    0.8 0.94    0.99    0.63    0.82    0.53    0.63    0.58    0.4 0.56    0.33    0.24    0.51    0.06    0.52
}\polardata

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\plotsperrow}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\scalingfactor}{0.5}

\begin{figure}[p]
\foreach \x in {1,...,30}
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\scalingfactor]
    \begin{polaraxis}[xmin=-90,xmax=90]
        \addplot table
        [   x=ang,
            y=f\x,
        ] {\polardata};
    \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mynewline}{mod(\x-1,\plotsperrow) == \plotsperrow -1 ? 1 : 0}
    \ifthenelse{1 = \mynewline}{\\}{}
}
\caption{many bogus plots}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks for the solution, this could be the way, in my case I wanted the data to be located all together in main `.tex` file, so I decided to write a 2D array of semicircles using two `\foreach` cycles with the plot's coordinates only in `tikzpicture` environment manually.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, as the best solution I have chosen manually placing the plots in `tikzpicture` environment. The source code is shown here and the output below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.63]
    \foreach \r in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6} {
        \foreach \c in {0,1,2} {
            \draw ({\c*6.5+0.5},{26-(\r+1)*4+0.5}) -- ({(\c+1)*6.5-0.5},{26-(\r+1)*4+0.5}); % x-axis
            \draw ({(\c+1)*6.5-0.5},{26-(\r+1)*4+0.5}) arc (0:180:2.75); % y-axis
            \foreach \a/\l in {30/60,60/30,90/0,120/-30,150/-60} { % angles
                \draw[black!30] ({\c*6.5+3.25},{26-(\r+1)*4+0.5}) -- ({\c*6.5+3.25+2.75*cos(\a)},{26-(\r+1)*4+0.5+2.75*sin(\a)});
                \draw ({\c*6.5+3.25+3*cos(\a)},{26-(\r+1)*4+0.5+3*sin(\a)}) node[scale=0.5] {\l°};
            }
            \foreach \b/\m in {0/0,0.25/20,0.5/40,0.75/60} { % dB
                \draw[black!30] ({(\c+1)*6.5-3.25+2.75*\b},{26-(\r+1)*4+0.5}) arc (0:180:{2.75*\b});
                \draw ({(\c+1)*6.5-3.05+2.75*\b},{26-(\r+1)*4+0.63}) node[scale=0.5] {\m};
            }
            \draw ({(\c+1)*6.5-3+2},{26-(\r+1)*4+0.27}) node[scale=0.5] {[dB]};
        }
    }
    % those have to be placed manually [or I don't know the way to automatize it]
    \coordinate[label=below:100 Hz] () at (3.25,22.6);
    \draw   (4.4,22.5) -- ...
    \coordinate[label=below:125 Hz] () at (9.75,22.6);
    \draw   (11.1,22.5) -- ...
    ... and the other frequencies
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Manually placed polar-axis groupplot]